# Adding Literals inside an ASP Hyperlink Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am creating ASP.NET Hyperlink controls programatically from the code behind like so:

```
 Dim theBritishFlag As New HyperLink()
 theBritishFlag.ImageUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("blobStorageURLHTTP") & "assets/images/winASafari/enFlag.png"
 theBritishFlag.NavigateUrl = sectionFunctions.getSectionLink(Request.QueryString("sectionID"), "en", "gb")
```

Notice that I setting the ImageUrl property of the Hyperlink which means on the page, the hyperlink is rendered like so:

```
    <a href="../../../../fr/fr/s/3499/meet-a-cheetah-home.aspx">
    <img src="../assets/images/winASafari/frFlag.png" alt="" />
<!-- this is where the Literal should go--></a>
```

I would like to add a new ASP Literal like the one below inside of my Hyperlink code above:

```
 Dim theBritishFlagText As New Literal()
        theBritishFlagText.Text = "English"
        theBritishFlag.Controls.Add(theBritishFlagText)
```

Does the ASP Hyperlink allow for child controls (such as Literals) to be added to it (inside of its rendered `<a>` tags? Because I am finding that this is not working (no text appears inside of the rendered `<a>` tags)

I have tagged with VB.NET and C# because this web app uses both.

(And yes I've properly added all controls featured above to the page.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it

```
theBritishFlag .Controls.Add(theBritishFlagText)
```

Update

I have tested this and it works. Have you added your hyperlink to page's control ??

```
HyperLink abc = new HyperLink();
            abc.NavigateUrl = "www.someurl.com";

            Literal xy = new Literal();
            xy.Text = "Click Here";

            abc.Controls.Add(xy); //add literal to hyperlink control

 Image i = new Image();
             i.ImageUrl = "http://www.google.co.in/intl/en_ALL/images/logos/images_logo_lg.gif";
             abc.Controls.Add(i); //add image 

            this.Controls.Add(abc); //add hyperlink to page control
```

Comment: How is this an answer?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin - Do not get over excited and downvote. I just said you should be able to do it. You know what, now I would follow you and see all your answers

Comment: Don't take a downvote so personally, your original answer provided no value to the question at all. Just saying "what you did should work" is not an answer by itself.

Comment: Some times when you eliminate all other possiblities of error it self solves a bug. the op is confused about wheather adding a literal control inside a hyperlink would work or not. If he could be sure that not the area where the bug is, he could concentrate on the other area. Its help ful for the person who asked the questionb, Its not help ful for because you are just wasting  your time down voting  other people's effort

Comment: Thank you. All I needed to know is whether ASP Hyperlinks can have child controls inside of them.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin - Read the above comment !

Comment: @Anand Although.. You failed to take into account the fact that I was using the `ImageUrl` property for the ASP Hyperlink which is in fact not possible to do with text - I reached an alternative solution.

Comment: Yes, but you would be able add image to hyperlink as you have added the text. I have updated the answer

Comment: @adaam - so what was the solution you used? can you post it here?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin Funnily enough it is the same solution as Anand has posted above (adding an Image control to the hyperlink as well as the text)

Comment: nice, +1 then after he added some real content to his answer.